# Import dependency on Angular CLI

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to import some dependency on Angular CLI in my module

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
```

it's work when i put in angular-cli.json in script: [] but when i put it in my app.module thats dependency didnt work at all.

Hopefully someone can describe what happen with my app.

Comment: That's because you have to install the `typings` for it which will give access to `*.d.ts`.

Comment: did you try to add it in the polyfills.ts file ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work is because you didn't install a [Typescript declaration file (aka `*.d.ts`)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) for the associated libraries. Thus, enter these commands in your console:

```bash
npm install --save @types/jquery # Install jquery type declaration
npm install --save @types/bootstrap # Install bootstrap type declaration
```

Comment: still get "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function" error message after i install those. 
but if i put "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" etc in angular-cli.json thats work fine, but i got messy design css